# Partition and PartitionBy in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

What's a difference between `partiton` and `partitionby` in Spark?

For example, what's happening here?

```
JavaPairRDD<scala.Tuple1<String>, row> rddH = rddHB.partitionBy(new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(6));
```

Answer (score 0):

A partition in spark is an chunk of data (logical division of data) stored on a node in the cluster. Partitions are basic units of parallelism in Apache Spark.

`partitionBy()` is a `DataFrameWriter` method that specifies if the data should be written to disk in folders.

Further reading - [Partitioning on Disk with partitionBy](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/partitionby/)

#### Update :

Consider this example

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object PartitionByExample extends App {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)


  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(getClass.getName)
    .master("local[*]").getOrCreate

  import spark.implicits._

  //create a dataframe with demo data
  val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    (1, "Fname1", "Lname1", "Belarus"),
    (2, "Fname1", "Lname1", "Belarus"),
    (3, "Fname2", "Lname2", "Belgium"),

    (3, "Fname2", "Lname2", "Belgium"),
    (4, "Fname3", "Lname3", "Austria"),
    (5, "Fname4", "Lname4", "Australia"),
    (6, "Fname4", "Lname4", "Australia")
  )).toDF("id", "fname", "lname", "country")


  //save the data with partitionby first letter of country

  df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("country").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("outputpath")

  import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

  // this is paired rdd
  val rddOneP: RDD[(String, String)] = df.rdd.map {
    x => (x.getAs[String]("id"), x.getAs[String]("country"))
  }
  rddOneP.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(6)).saveAsTextFile("outputpath1")
  println(" partition By here .. .Return a copy of the RDD partitioned using the specified partitioner.")
}
```

#### Case 1 :

***which has dataframe partitionBy to write the same country information in to one csv file***

[image]

#### Case 2

***PairedRDD with your style partitionBy... :***
**It will create 6 partitions based on the hashcode of elements** it will try to store/save (since I saved as text file)
[image]

---

> try to execute above if possible you will understand your self. *One is*
> *DataFrame another one is pariedRDD ... second one is as good as*
> *`repartition(6)` since repartition uses hashpartitioner.*

if you remove

```
  rddOneP.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(6)).saveAsTextFile("outputpath1")
```

and add

```
 rddOneP.repartition(6).saveAsTextFile("outputpath1")
```

to above program you will get same kind of output...

Comment: You also have [`partitionBy()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html#partitionBy-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) for window functions. Unclear which one is refered to in the question.

Comment: @Ram, In partitionBy() we pass column names to be partitioned on disk. But what's happening in code snippet ? (Updated in Question)  Not passing column names at all

Comment: check the answer. pls dont update incrementally. In the first place ask well formed question.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram, so partitionBy() is used only to specify output file patterns on disk. Its completely different from partition, which actually splits the dataset for parallel executions. Correct ?

Comment: yes as afore mentioned... partitionBy in case of Parid RDD "splits the dataset for parallel executions" but I also saved that on disk.  Imagine if you wont save to the disk then still it is unitt of parllelism right ? means data is splitted based on hash value and its eligible for applying any logic which works in parllel right.. dont get confused by `DataFrameWriter` `partitionBy` witth `RDD` `partitonBy.`

Comment: any other thing you wanted to know.... Appreciate your feedback on the answer given. it s motivation to give more answers.